# Unable to run celery task directly but still possible via Python console

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq, celery, celery-task

I'd like to run a simple test (run a task) first via RabbitMQ and once this is setup correctly, then encapsulate in Docker and run from there.

My structure looks like so:

```
-rabbitmq_docker
    - test_celery
        - __init__.py
        - celeryapp.py
        - celeryconfig.py
        - runtasks.py
        - tasks.py
    - docker-compose.yml    
    - dockerfile
    - requirements.txt
```

**celeryconfig.py**

```
## List of modules to import when celery starts
CELERY_IMPORTS = ['test_celery.tasks',] # Required to import module containing tasks

## Message Broker (RabbitMQ) settings
CELERY_BROKER_URL = "amqp://guest@localhost//"
CELERY_BROKER_PORT = 5672

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'rpc://'
```

**celeryapp.py**

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('test_celery')
app.config_from_object('test_celery.celeryconfig', namespace='CELERY')
```

**__init__.py**

```
from .celeryapp import app as celery_app
```

**run_tasks.py**

```
from tasks import reverse
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
LOGGER = get_task_logger(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    async_result = reverse.delay("rabbitmq")
    LOGGER.info(async_result.get())
```

**tasks.py**

```
from test_celery.celeryapp import app

@app.task(name='tasks.reverse')
def reverse(string):
    return string[::-1]
```

I run `celery -A test_celery worker --loglevel=info` from the `rabbitmq_docker` directory. Then in a separate window I trigger `reverse.delay("rabbitmq")` in the Python console, after importing the required module. This works. Now when I try to trigger the reverse function via the `run_tasks.py` i.e. `python test_celery/run_tasks.py` I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_celery/run_tasks.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tasks import reverse
  File "/Users/my_mbp/Software/rabbitmq_docker/test_celery/tasks.py", line 1, in <module>
    from test_celery.celeryapp import app
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test_celery'
```

What I don't get is why this Traceback doesn't get thrown when called directly from the Python console. Could anyone help me out here? I'd eventually like to startup docker, and just run the tests automatically (without going into the Python console).

Comment: What happens if you move `run_tasks.py` to the same level as `test_celery` and then change the first line to `from test_celery.tasks import reverse`?

Comment: @PyPingu of course, that was the trick.

Comment: Good, your issue was due to the way python looks for modules during imports. You can try reading [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) thoroughly, and also moving around imports/files to get a better understanding. Although honestly I get confused by it myself sometimes :)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is simply because your module is not in the Python path.
These should help:

- Specify the PYTHONPATH to point to the directory where your test_celery package.
- Always run your Python code in the directory where your test_celery package is located.
- Or alternatively reorganise your imports...